# Spam Prevention

Tags: support, spam

Just tried to post an answer to a question on stack overflow and found it a bit more difficult than it should be.

First of all I included 2 links for the user to reference. Both links were part of w3schools.com. Both completely relevant to the post. I could only post one which was very annoying.

I edited out a link, then resubmitted my answer. I then get a robot screen asking me to fill out a captcha.

While I understand how spam is a problem. Wouldn't it be simpler and less hassle for the user if someone trying to post more than one link got a captcha?

This way the answer could contain relevant reference links + the answer can be submitted without being stopped twice.

Comment: Don't link to w3schools. It's a bad site. Use MDN instead.

Answer (score 6):

This is only until you get a bit more rep, after that you can add as many links as you want. The Captcha and spam detection might be a bit too enthusiastic at times, but they shouldn't be that bad. I'd rather fill in a Captcha every now and then, instead of having the site full of Viagra questions.

If a higher rep user sees your answer, maybe he'll edit it to properly hyperlink everything. Until you get your rep up, just add them as text, it's fine that way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post more links, because you do not have enough rep. The system uses rep to decide if it can trust a user or not. Even if you pass the Captcha, then that does not mean you're trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought that the Captcha is triggered by rapid editing, and it doesn't seem to happen if I take my time.

Of course, the incentive to post quick answers *and edit them* doesn't help me to slow down.